# How do you start a new python program in quickly/gedit?

Tags: application-development, quickly

I am trying to make an app in quickly, and I have made the windows, one is called test the other is called menu and the test is the start page, and I want to program it so when you click on the button (button1), it will load menu.ui. Here is all the code from TestWindow:

```
# -*- Mode: Python; coding: utf-8; indent-tabs-mode: nil; tab-width: 4 -*-
### BEGIN LICENSE
# This file is in the public domain
### END LICENSE
import gettext
from gettext import gettext as _
gettext.textdomain('test')

import gtk
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('test')
from test_lib import Window
from test.AboutTestDialog import AboutTestDialog
from test.PreferencesTestDialog import PreferencesTestDialog
import os
# See test_lib.Window.py for more details about how this class works
class TestWindow(Window):
    __gtype_name__ = "TestWindow"

    def finish_initializing(self, builder): # pylint: disable=E1002
        """Set up the main window"""
        super(TestWindow, self).finish_initializing(builder)

        self.AboutDialog = AboutTestDialog
        self.PreferencesDialog = PreferencesTestDialog

        # Code for other initialization actions should be added here.
    def on_button1_clicked(self, widget, data=None):
        print "Loading Menu!"
        os.chdir(r"/home/user/test/data/ui/")
        os.startfile("menu.ui")
```

The last 2 lines are my attempt at trying to make it start the menu.ui. Are there any ways to do this? Any help is appreciated!
Thanks
-Drex

Comment: Better suited for Stack Overflow, since they're the coding experts.

Comment: actually its about app development with quickly, which is a perfectly good question for askubuntu.com

Comment: App development, using Quickly, is on-topic and encouraged on Ask Ubuntu. Community driven Q&A for Ubuntu users *and developers*

Answer (score 1):

A good starting point for app development with quickly and python is here: http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/tutorials/all/diy-media-player-with-pygtk/

In general, you can see how quickly handles other `.ui` files in your code in the lines

```
from test.AboutTestDialog import AboutTestDialog
from test.PreferencesTestDialog import PreferencesTestDialog
[...]
self.AboutDialog = AboutTestDialog
self.PreferencesDialog = PreferencesTestDialog
```

You would add your new window the same way:

Create a new file for your menu window under your `test` directory, such that your code could look like this:

```
from test.AboutTestDialog import AboutTestDialog
from test.PreferencesTestDialog import PreferencesTestDialog
from test.MenuTestWindow import MenuTestWindow
[...]
self.AboutDialog = AboutTestDialog
self.PreferencesDialog = PreferencesTestDialog
self.MenuWindow = MenuTestWindow
```

Then you can show the Window in your `on_button1_clicked` method like this:

```
def on_button1_clicked(self, widget, data=None):
    print "Loading Menu!"
    self.MenuWindow.show()
```

Now the only question remaining is, what does your MenuTestWindow class look like? I would simply look into the quickly created classes and write something like this:

```
import gettext
from gettext import gettext as _
gettext.textdomain('test')

import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('test')

from test_lib.MenuWindow import MenuWindow

# See test_lib.MenuWindow for more details about how this class works.
class MenuTestWindow():
    __gtype_name__ = "MenuTestWindow"

    def finish_initializing(self, builder): # pylint: disable=E1002
        """Set up the about dialog"""
        super(MenuTestWindow, self).finish_initializing(builder)
        # Code for other initialization actions should be added here.
```

which leaves us with the `test_lib.MenuWindow` file and class (also stolen from the quickly defaults):

```
import gtk
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('test_lib')

from . helpers import get_builder, show_uri, get_help_uri
from . preferences import preferences

# This class is meant to be subclassed by MenuWindow.  It provides
# common functions and some boilerplate.
class Window(gtk.Window):
    __gtype_name__ = "Window"

    # To construct a new instance of this method, the following notable 
    # methods are called in this order:
    # __new__(cls)
    # __init__(self)
    # finish_initializing(self, builder)
    # __init__(self)
    #
    # For this reason, it's recommended you leave __init__ empty and put
    # your initialization code in finish_initializing

    def __new__(cls):
        """Special static method that's automatically called by Python when 
        constructing a new instance of this class.

        Returns a fully instantiated MenuTestWindow object.
        """
        builder = get_builder('MenuWindow')
        new_object = builder.get_object("menu_window")
        new_object.finish_initializing(builder)
        return new_object

    def finish_initializing(self, builder):
        """Called while initializing this instance in __new__

        finish_initializing should be called after parsing the UI definition
        and creating a TestWindow object with it in order to finish
        initializing the start of the new TestWindow instance.
        """
        # Get a reference to the builder and set up the signals.
        self.builder = builder
        self.ui = builder.get_ui(self, True)
```

(I hope I didn't miss anything... :-)

This should be all.

**However**: If I would be writing this application, I would probably not use a different `.ui` file, but place every additional gui/window in the main window `ui` file (lets call the new window MenuWindow) and access it via something like this:

```
def on_button1_clicked(self, widget, data=None):
    mw = self.builder.get_object("MenuWindow")
    mw.show()
```

This way you don't have to create all those other classes and files. But it is your app and you have to know yourself, if a separate `.ui` file is needed in your case.